# How to validate the phone number using react

Tags: reactjs, validation, plugins, libphonenumber

Currently, I'm checking to validate the mobile number using **'libphonenumber-js'** plugin in react.

It has a public method that is **isValidNumber** it has been used to validate the mobile number with extension code.

My problem i,m this function has accepted 11 digits Indian mobile number(Actually Indian mobile number has only 10 digits number ). How to solve this?

Actual Behavior

```
isValidNumber('+919876543210') => return true (10 digits)
isValidNumber('+91987654321') => return false (9 digits)
isValidNumber('+91987654321011') => return false  (12 digits)
isValidNumber('+9198765432101') => return true (11 digits) // Accepted 11 digits :-(
```

Expected Behavior

```
isValidNumber('+919876543210') => return true (10 digits)
isValidNumber('+91987654321') => return false (9 digits)
isValidNumber('+91987654321011') => return false  (12 digits)
isValidNumber('+9198765432101') => return false (11 digits) // It should be return false
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use npm package 'validator'.

```
npm install validator --save
```

then

```
import validator from 'validator' 

validatePhoneNumber = (number) => {
 const isValidPhoneNumber = validator.isMobilePhone(number)
 return (isValidPhoneNumber)
}


console.log(validatePhoneNumber('react')) //=> false
console.log(validatePhoneNumber('0641732123')) //=> true
```

you can also set the locale for specific countries (eg. 'en-ZA') and more as your options.

docs : https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: it has accept even 9 digits :-(        "+91971565313"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any problem to use any npm package then you can use

> https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/

package.
With this package, you can easily validate any phone number.

Comment: in this package they has used that 'libphonenumber-js'  for phone number validation

Comment: Package deleted

Comment: looks like it's been reinstated on github. Although the dev has said he's [moved over to gitlab](https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js#github). Both github and gitlab work now, but I believe gitlab should be considered the main source of truth

Answer (score 0):

```
var phone = '1234567890';
if( !(phone.match('[0-9]{10}')) ){
     alert('Please provide valid phone number');
}else{
     //good to go
}
```